# Struts 2.3.1.5 and jQuery Plugin v3.6 - trying to iterate data returned from JSON with nested object

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

We've spent couple of days trying to figure it out but we couldn't so we decide to ask for your opinion here.

We have a collection which returns a JSON data. The code beneath will render a table and a subgrid table. In the Parent table we've located some data which is okay. But in the subgrid table we're unable to load anything.

What are we doing wrong?

```
 {
   "sales":[
      {
         "client":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Jon Doe",
            "phone":"35900022233"
         },
         "goods":[
            {
               "description":"Good Description",
               "id":3,
               "name":"Good name",
               "price":10.0
            },
            {
               "description":"Good Description 2",
               "id":2,
               "name":"Good name 2",
               "price":1.87
            },
            {
               "description":"Good Description 3",
               "id":1,
               "name":"Good name 3",
               "price":2.5
            }
         ]
}
```

<s:url var="sales" value="/getSales"/>

```
<sjg:grid
    id="salesTable"
    caption="Sales List"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{sales}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="sales"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
    width="900"
    shrinkToFit="true"
    viewrecords="true"
>

    <sjg:grid 
        id="goodssubgridtable"
        caption="Goods"
        dataType="json"
        subGridUrl="%{sales}"
        gridModel="goods"
        width="true"
        shrinkToFit="false"
    >
    
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name"  title="Name"  />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="description"  title="Description"  />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="price" title="Price" />
</sjg:grid>

<sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" width="50" title="ID" sortable="false"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="quantity" index="quantity" width="200" title="Quantity" sortable="false" />
<sjg:gridColumn name="totalAmount" index="totalAmount" width="300" title="Total amount" sortable="false" />
<sjg:gridColumn name="client.id" title="Client ID" width="100"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="client.name" title="Client name" />
<sjg:gridColumn name="client.phone" title="Phone number" />
```

</sjg:grid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Goods` is not in the root of the object returned, you should use the right path in the notation, like `gridModel="sales[0].goods"` .

Refer to [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1654265) for more details on how to traverse JSON objects.

Edit: the JSON you posted here seems malformed, but it's probably just a copy & paste issue; however, try with an hardcoded index; if it works, you should get, IF POSSIBLE, the index of the row to pass through OGNL, since you are not inside an `iterator`, but inside a custom tag :/

But looking at [the official Showcase's source code](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/src/main/webapp/pages/grid-subgrid.jsp?r=1641), it is done in a completely different way: two different URLs pointing to two different Actions for the Grid and the subGrid. I think that is the way it is meant to be used. Browse the repository to find the Actions too if you need to check the business they perform

Comment: We have tried that alogn with many other ways. But this solution is not working for us.

Comment: Well in our case the parent grid is loading correctly we are able to display the data wich we desire. But the problem is with the sub-grid which expands after the "+" is clicked, in the second table nothing is displayed. Eaven when we change the gridModel to gridModel = "sales.goods"